# Why does Apache2 map www.myurl.com/php to this directory?

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I've recently inherited the job of maintaining a LAMP server. I have basically zero experience with web development, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious or not giving the right information.

If I go to `www.myurl.com/foo/someFile.php`, I get `someFile.php` located in `/directory/number/one/foo`. This is what I would expect since `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` contains:

```
<Directory /directory/number/one/foo>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

However, if I go to `www.myurl.com/php/someFile.php`, then I get someFile.php located in `/directory/number/two/` (In real life `/directory/number/two/` is `/home/sean/sean_test/`, so it's not some default path). I haven't been able to find any references to `/directory/number/two/` in any of the following places:

- Any `httpd.conf` on the system
- Any `apache2.conf`
- Any file in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`
- Any `.htaccess` on the system
- Any `php.ini` on the system
- Any `.user.ini` on the system (none exist, but they are referenced by php.ini)

I also haven't been able to find any symlinks from `php` to `/directory/number/two/` anywhere on the system. Why is Apache loading files from `/directory/number/two/`?

Output of `/usr/sbin/apache2 -V`:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Mar  3 2013 12:09:44
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Output of `php --version`:

```
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar  4 2013 13:11:17) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
```